# How does the comparision operator work for string data types in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var a = 'abcdefg';
var b = 'abczefg';

// false
a > b
```

How does the Javascirpt engine work with the above code. Does it compare each letter?
I am interested to know if the code will break in once it encounters 'z' and return false or does it go till the end to compare and then return false?

Comment: [Comparing String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Comparing_strings).

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison

Comment: Why are you using `String` objects instead of actual strings?

Comment: Just to make it obvious

Comment: @crystal_test To make what obvious? Objects and strings behave differently.

Comment: Yes. But I am interested to know how Compare operator works for a string

Comment: @melpomene I'll Change them to actual strings.

Comment: Probably different on different browsers, but probably compares few characters at a time instead of one by one

Comment: @NinaScholz This question is about the implementation, your duplicate is about the abstract operation.

Answer (score 0):

From the standard, without mention any implementation:

> [7.2.12 Abstract Relational Comparison](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison)
>
> The comparison of Strings uses a simple lexicographic ordering on sequences of code unit values. There is no attempt to use the more complex, semantically oriented definitions of character or string equality and collating order defined in the Unicode specification. Therefore String values that are canonically equal according to the Unicode standard could test as unequal. In effect this algorithm assumes that both Strings are already in normalized form. Also, note that for strings containing supplementary characters, lexicographic ordering on sequences of UTF-16 code unit values differs from that on sequences of code point values.

The implementation is vendor specific.

Comment: Yes. I know that.I know the behavior of the operator and know what would be the result. But I am interested how the mechanism works for

Comment: do mean the comparison operator?

Comment: Yes..comparision operator

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript specification just describes the abstract behavior of the comparison operators, not their implementation. So anything is theoretically possible, so long as it produces the correct result.

However, any implementation that loops over the entire strings before returning an answer would be incredibly stupid. Imagine two strings of a million characters that differ in their first characters -- there's no good reason to compare all the remaining characters, since they have no impact on the result.

It might not compare exactly character by character, as there may be machine operations that operate on words at a time, but it would be very surprising to see an implementation that doesn't stop comparing within a few bytes of the first difference.

Answer (score 0):

The deepest I can go in the specification, it says this about `localeCompare` which probably is similar to what you are looking for:

> [21.1.3.10 String.prototype.localeCompare](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.localecompare)
>
> The two Strings are compared in an implementation-defined fashion. The result is intended to order String values in the sort order specified by a host default locale, and will be negative, zero, or positive, depending on whether S comes before That in the sort order, the Strings are equal, or S comes after That in the sort order, respectively.

The implementation cannot be specific, and here's what they say about it:

> The actual return values are implementation-defined to permit implementers to encode additional information in the value, but the function is required to define a total ordering on all Strings. This function must treat Strings that are canonically equivalent according to the Unicode standard as identical and must return 0 when comparing Strings that are considered canonically equivalent.

What we can be sure of, is that it can depend on the default locale rather than only character comparison operator. Nonetheless, to answer one of your questions, yes, the algorithm will stop whenever a bigger character is found, because once a string becomes bigger it cannot become equal or smaller afterwards (but I might be wrong on that, if someone finds a scenario in which it happens with a specific locale, I will happily update my answer). The direction of the iterations, however, can be either LTR (left to right) or RTL (right to left) depending on your locale so a correct implementation should also care about that.